# position of two textview and a imageview in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, textview

I am preparing a custom `listview`. I want to achieve this

[image]

I am quite confused, how to put an `imageview` along with `textview` in `linearlayout`. So, my question is how to put an `imageview` along with `textview` in `linearlayout`, like in the image. I tried this, but still I couldn't able to implement the two textview with an imageview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Still, I couldn't implement this. But, I am going to  try with this one

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abTopic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" >

        <!-- Title -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <!-- Rightend Arrow -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemArrow"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        <!-- SubTitle -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/absubTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/abTitle"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and make change according to you.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text=" " 
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayouts have the property [`android:gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3agravity) that will move it's child elements as far to one border as possible. In your case you would want a LinearLayout for each row with two LinearLayout children. In the first LinearLayout do `android:gravity="left"` and in the second do `android:gravity="right"`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put your image to textview's background ? and you can use `android:gravity="right"` for some of your list items

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code and adjust according to your need:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-18dp"
        android:background="#003f84"
        android:text="Text2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

if any doubt then please feel free write to me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve my problem by myself.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Topic -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abTopic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#003f84"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <!-- View -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <!-- Type -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#003f84"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip" >

            <!-- Title -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:paddingRight="25dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <!-- Rightend Arrow -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemArrow"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

            <!-- Subtitle -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SubTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/abTitle"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:paddingRight="25dip"
                android:textColor="#666362"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```